# react-select async callback is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, loadoptions

I'm using react-select's AsyncSelect component, and try to [resolve it from a callback](https://react-select.com/async#loading-asynchronously) with the following code:

```
loadOptions(inputValue, callback) {
  this.props.asyncFunctionWithCallback(resp => {
    callback(resp);
  });
}
```

`asyncFunctionWithCallback()` is an async function that receives a callback 
    that is called when the promise is resolved:

```
asyncFunctionWithCallback(doneCallback) {
  // Call some async code
  fetch(url).then(response => { 
    doneCallback(response) 
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call react-select's `callback()` from within `asyncFunctionWithCallback()`'s callback, but seems like it is not being called, as `asyncFunctionWithCallback()` is being called repeatedly forever.

I guess I'm not passing the callback properly, but cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass on the res.json value from fetch to the callback like

```
asyncFunctionWithCallback(doneCallback) {
  // Call some async code
  fetch(url)..then(res => res.json())then(response => { 
    doneCallback(response) 
  }
}
```

However since you already have an async code its better to use the promist approach for loadOptions

```
loadOptions(inputValue) {
  return this.props.asyncFunctionWithCallback();
}

asyncFunctionWithCallback() {
  // Call some async code
  return fetch(url)..then(res => res.json());
}
```